# Java: User Authenticate Using Jersey Jax-RS with Spring Security

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, jersey

I am trying to use Jersey Jax-RS Api and Spring-Security for user authenticate. But i am enable to do this. Jersey provide some basic authentication methods, but i need to use spring-security. I am trying manually `UserName` and `Password` authenticate by spring security, but it thrown and null pointer exception. Follwoing is my code :

```
@Path(value = "/")
public class UserLoginApi {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@POST
@Path(value = "test")
public void test() {
    System.out
            .println("Hello REST **************************************** ");
}

@POST
@Path(value = "login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response userlogin(User user, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    User user2 = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    System.out.println(user2);
    return Response.status(200).entity("OK").build();
}
}
```

In this code the `authenticationManager` is null, so it thrown an exception. Is there is a another way for do this? or using jersey the `Spring-Security` is not possible?

Please provide some way for do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use spring security in your project you should use **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter** -> [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html)

and override *attemptAuthentication* method.
In the body of this method you will be able to get your username and password from HttpRequest.

Please remember to configure your spring security using spring-security.xml file.

Later in your controller UserLoginApi  you will be able to check if your user authenticated successfully using *SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()*.

See also classes:

- org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler
- org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler
- org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint